# Can I use a VPN to access services only available to a specific network?

Tags: vpn, tunneling

I am a member of a library which has access to online databases that I use for work. The databases can only be accessed when you are on library's WIFI network. If I try to use the same databases from another location or when I am not using that particular WIFI network, I do not have access.

The problem is, that during the COVID restrictions the library is not open and I can't use their WIFI network.

I use Nord VPN, is it possible to set my IP address or change my DNS settings to make it appear that I am using that library's WIFI so I can access the database from anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

VPN, yes; Nord VPN no

A VPN allows you to tunnel your traffic such that it will appear that you are physically on the destination network.  If said library was hosting a vpn, your idea would work splendidly, however, Nord VPN will most assuredly not have a gateway inside this libraries network.

It would theoretically be possible to setup a remote device on-prem and tunnel to it using SSH, but as the library is closed, it would be difficult.